# Devise метод after_update_path_for не редиректит на указанный адрес

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Я использовал стандартный devise метод переадресации после апдейта,но к сожалению он не работает.`routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users

root "welcome#index"

get "/profile" => "profile#index", as: :profile
```

вот мой `application_controller.rb`

```
def after_update_path_for(resource)
  profile_path
end
```

в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны унаследовать свой собственный контроллер `RegistrationsController` от контроллера Divise `Devise::RegistrationsController` и уже в нем переопределить путь

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def after_update_path_for(_resource)
    profile_path
  end
end
```

Кроме того, поправьте ваш `devise_for` в config/routes.rb следующим образом

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: :registrations }
```

Comment: Странно,я сделал как Вы сказали,но тем не менее не работает

Comment: @holden ну, это не совсем всё... его надо ещё указать в роутах, в вызове `devise_for`.

Comment: @D-side спасибо за замечание, с вашего позволения добавлю его в ответ.

Comment: в инете копался, сам нашел,но всем спасибо за помощь!!!

Answer (score 1):

Нашел и решил.Конечно же,необходимо в роутах путь верный указать,чтобы обращался к моему контроллеру `routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
```

и все прекрасно работает